# JPA/Hibernate dynamic tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

currently I'm on a project where I need to persist uploaded Excel/CSV files to a database table.
For every uploaded file a new table with the same structure (+ some technical columns) should be created.
After this the database table will be shown within a webpage as HTML-table. This table will provide basic CRUD-functionalities for every dataset.

Now I'm deciding wheter to use JDBC-functions directly or using JPA, which would be much "cleaner" in my opinion. In a  second step I want to publish this data via OData with Olingo Framework.

But I have no idea, how I should build this generic table structure (every Excel might have a very different set of columns) with  JPA functions. There is no static POJO structure in my use case.

Does anyone of you has  an idea how my use case could be modeled with Hibernate without knowing how the final structures will look like?

A second thought was to build a generic POJO with following attributes

- (String) table name
- (List) columns
- (List) datasets

But with this structure the whole dataset would always be updated. Not a good solution when a table might have hundret thousands of entries.
Using a database like Mongo is also no solution because relational database is required in this project (for further use cases). Otherwise I could persist this excel via json.

Greetings!

Comment: Eclipselink has Dynamic Entities (non JPA standard, as extension). In general JPA isnt well prepaded to unknown tables

Comment: Look into Hibernate's Dynamic MapMode for entities.  It basically allows you to specify a table name and a Map of key/value pairs for the data that should be stored.  That should work just nicely for your use case.

Comment: Thanks! I will look deeper into dynamic mapmode.

Answer (score 0):

This process of Bulk is up to use JPA or Hibernate, but working with a generic model wouldn't be a great deal.

1. The entity class must be annotated with the javax.persistence.Entity annotation (or be denoted as such in XML mapping)
2. The entity class must have a public or protected no-argument constructor. It may define additional constructors as well.
3. The entity class must be a top-level class.
4. The entity class must not be final. No methods or persistent instance variables of the entity class may be final.

etc ...

i work with a generic entity table, here is the strutucture :

```
CREATE TABLE T_SPPI_DETT_ENTITY
(
  ID                NUMBER(12)           NOT NULL,
  ATTR_NAME         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)    NOT NULL,
  ATTR_VALUE            VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
  ATTR_DATE              DATE
) 

ALTER TABLE  T_SPPI_DETT_ENTITY ADD (
  CONSTRAINT T_DETT_ENTITY_PK  PRIMARY KEY  (ID, ATTR_NAME)
  USING INDEX T_DETT_ENTITY_PK  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

For query at this table JPA/Hibernate is not a good approach, i use :
 Oracle  `PIVOT`

Comment: Thanks for this idea. But I worry about table size and performance when application grows up to multi million entities.